# Image of smooth manifold is a submanifold

Tags: analysis, differential-topology

It's know that if $M$ is a compact, smooth manifold of dimension $n$ and the map $f: M \to \mathbb{R^m}$ is injective, smooth, $n \le m$ and $Jf(a)$, the Jacobian, has rank $n$ for every $a \in M$, then $f(M)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R^m}$.  I'm trying to think of a counterexample to this statement if we suppose $M$ is not compact, but haven't gotten anywhere.  Can anyone offer a hint?

Comment: Take an open interval and map it into the plane such that it forms a figure "6". Focus on that non-manifold point on the 6 and think about how you can make something like that and still have an injective mapping.

Comment: You can't do that with a proper map  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map

Answer (score 1):

Let $g\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{T}^2= \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ be given by $t\mapsto [(t,\alpha t)]$, where $\alpha$ is any irrational number. The image of $g$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{T}^2$ but $g$ is not surjective. Hence, $\mathrm{Im}(g)$ cannot be a submanifold of $\mathbb{T}^2$. Compose this map with the embedding of the torus into $\mathbb{R}^3$.